# Setting Points of Interest (POI) off on EGMap Google Maps Extension for yii

Tags: yii

I am using the EGMap extension with yii framework to work with Google maps. I want to disable the POIs on the map.

I know that this can be done in the usual way as:

```
styles:[{
        featureType:"poi",
        elementType:"labels",
        stylers:[{
            visibility:"off"
        }]
    }]
```

But how do I do it on yii?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

just looked in the extensions code, try call `setOptions` on the map object as this function is to set google map options.

from the EGMAP extension source (EGMap.php)

```
/**
 * 
 * Sets Google Map Options
 * @param array $options
 * 
 */
public function setOptions($options)
{
    $this->options = CMap::mergeArray($this->options, $options);
}
```